# How can I host multiple servers behind Nginx?

Tags: wordpress, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have a few servers running behind nginx. They are running on a few different independent computers running Windows Server 2022. I have media.mywebsite, qbit.mywebsite, mcweb.mywebsite, and note.mywebsite. I'm now starting to play with a fresh install of wordpress, cards.mywebsite hopefully, in a docker container. The issue is, even with what I think is the correct nginx config, when I go to cards.mywebsite, I get a HTTPS error saying it got the certificate from qbit.mywebsite. I click continue anyway and it opens qbit.mywebsite instead, but with the link of cards.mywebsite. Accessing it locally does just fine.  I'm not super familar with nginx, docker, or backend wordpress. Nginx is only being used to get the multiple servers to the web. Here's the shortened nginx config, any help would be appreciated

```
server entry for qbit
    server {
            listen      443;
            server_name  qbit.mywebsite;
        ssl_certificate      C:\sslqbit\certificate.crt;
            ssl_certificate_key  C:\sslqbit\private.key;
        location / {
                        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
                    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host:$server_port;
                   }
           }
 enforce HTTPS on qbit.
    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  qbit.mywebsite;
        return 301   https://$host$request_uri;
           }
server entry for cards.
    server {
        listen       443 ssl;
            server_name  cards.mywebsite;
         ssl_certificate      C:\sslcards\certificate.crt;
            ssl_certificate_key  C:\sslcards\private.key;
        location / {
                        proxy_pass http://localhost:32769;
                   }
               }
 enforce HTTPS on cards.
    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  cards.mywebsite;
        return 301   https://$host$request_uri;
           }
}
```

I've tried rewriting the entire config, drafting similar versions, and of course the grand google machine to no avail.

Comment: Use `nginx -T` (uppercase `T`) to view the entire configuration across all included files and ensure that the `cards.mywebsite` server blocks appear.

Comment: @RichardSmith I gaev that a whirl and it only showed me the nginx.conf, which is the only one that I've ever changed. Is it supposed to show up elsewhere?